# org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: document is not defined

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-mvc, graalvm, graaljs

> I am using Spring boot 2.4.4, JDK 1.8, and created ScriptEngine as shown.
> Page loaded perfectly for the first time but the second time it throws the exception mentioned below.

```
@Bean
public ScriptEngine scriptEngine() {
    ScriptEngine engine = new ScriptEngineManager().getEngineByName("graal.js");
    Bindings bindings = engine.getBindings(ScriptContext.ENGINE_SCOPE);
    bindings.put("polyglot.js.allowAllAccess", true);
    bindings.put("polyglot.js.allowHostClassLookup", true);
    //engine.setBindings(bindings, ScriptContext.GLOBAL_SCOPE);
    return engine;
}

org.graalvm.polyglot.PolyglotException: ReferenceError: document is not defined
<js>.:anonymous(<eval>:13)
<js>.:anonymous(<eval>:13)
<js>.r(<eval>:1)
<js>.:anonymous(<eval>:13)
<js>.:anonymous(<eval>:13)
<js>.r(<eval>:1)
<js>.:anonymous(<eval>:13)
<js>.:anonymous(<eval>:13)
<js>.r(<eval>:1)
<js>.:anonymous(<eval>:1)
<js>.:program(<eval>:1)
org.graalvm.polyglot.Context.eval(Context.java:344)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to install Java 11+ and latest karate jar